# Analog of Fubini's theorem for Borel functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f\colon [0,a]\times [0,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a Borel function, where $a>0$ and $b>0$.
Let $\mathscr F$ denote the space of Borel functions $[0,b]\to \mathbb R$, and let us endow this space with the topology of pointwise convergence.
For any $x\in [0,a]$ let $f_x$ denote the "slice" $f_x(y):=f(x,y)$.

Is the following claim true, or is there any similar characterization of Borel functions on $[0,a]\times [0,b]$:

**Claim.** A function $f\colon [0,a]\times [0,b] \to \mathbb R$ is Borel if and only if

1. for any $x\in[0,a]$ the slice $f_x$ is Borel (as a function $[0,b]\to \mathbb R$)
2. the function $x\mapsto f_x$ is Borel (as a function $[0,a]\to \mathscr F$)

This claim is somewhat similar to the fact that $L^1([0,a]\times [0,b]) = L^1([0,a]; L^1([0,b]))$ which follows from Fubini's theorem. But in the claim above we say nothing about the measure...

Note that if $f\colon [0,a]\times [0,b] \to \mathbb R$ is Borel then point 1 holds, because intersection of any Borel set with $\{x\}\times[0,b]$ is Borel for any $x\in [0,a]$. Is the point 2 true? Also note that point 1 on its own is not sufficient for $f$ to be Borel (take $f(x,y)=g(x)$ where $g$ is not Borel).